# check number falls between range

Tags: vba, excel, macros

[image: This is the format how i want]

column A and Column C is the range  and column B is the reference value which I have to compare with Column A and Column C .
Eg:   (B>A) and (B

Basically I want to check whether column B falls between Column A and column C

Here is the code which I have prepared but this is not working and this is for single cell:

```
Sub a()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

    x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    Z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value

    If Z > x Then
          Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = "Correct"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way:

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
        With .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC2>=RC1,RC2<=RC3),""Correct"",""Wrong"")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RajKumar, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple formula for this:

`=IF(AND(B1>=A1,B1<=C1),"Correct","Wrong")`

[image]

If you still need vba then use this:

```
Sub RANGEFALL()
Dim wk As Worksheet, frow As Long, i As Long

Set wk = Sheet1
frow = wk.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To frow
    If wk.Range("B" & i).Value >= wk.Range("A" & i).Value And wk.Range("B" & i).Value <= wk.Range("C" & i).Value Then
        wk.Range("D" & i).Value = "Correct"
    Else
        wk.Range("D" & i).Value = "Wrong"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i want to do it with VBA becoz i have huge data set.so it is not possible to drag it down to all.

Comment: You can just double click at the right bottom corner of the cell which has the formula and it will fill it to the last non empty cell